# Como criar uma variável dentro da tabela que seja resultado da verificação de relação entre duas tabelas diferentes?

Tags: r

Tenho duas tabelas `banco1.csv` e `banco2.csv`.
As duas tem em comum `id` e `cpf`;
O `banco1.csv` é minha "tabela principal".

Preciso verificar cruzar as informações (no R) das tabelas e criar uma coluna (no `banco1`) que me informe se aquele registro existe ou não na outra tabela (que seria `banco2`).

Exemplo:

**banco1**

| id | cpf | nome | existe_em_banco2* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 000 | João | Não |
| 2 | 111 | Marta | Sim |
| 3 | 222 | Jonas | Sim |

*essa coluna seria produto do cruzamento

**banco2**

| id | cpf | nome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 000 | Robson |
| 2 | 111 | Marta |
| 3 | 222 | Jonas |

Não sei se me fiz claro, mas com falta de conhecimento técnico fica difícil até de explicar a perguntar... Enfim.

Comment: Não entendi o exemplo. `id = 1` e `cpf = 000` existem nos dois bancos de dados para pessoas diferentes. O objetivo é comparar os nomes das pessoas com mesmo `id` e `cpf` e ver se eles são diferentes entre os bancos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que *id* ou *cpf*  sejam únicos em cada banco, pode usar `intersect` para determinar as linhas em comum entre os dois data.frames, e `ifelse` para converter TRUE/FALSE para Sim/Não. Vou usar *cpf*:

### Com tidyverse

```
library(dplyr)

banco1 %>% mutate(existe_em_banco2 = ifelse(cpf %in% intersect(banco1, banco2)$cpf, "Sim", "Não"))
#>   id  cpf  nome existe_em_banco2
#> 1  1 00-0  João              Não
#> 2  2 11-1 Marta              Sim
#> 3  3 22-2 Jonas              Sim
```

### Com data.table

```
library(data.table)

setDT(banco1)
setDT(banco2)

banco1[, existe_em_banco2 := fifelse(cpf %in% fintersect(banco1, banco2)$cpf, "Sim", "Não")]

banco1
#>    id  cpf  nome existe_em_banco2
#> 1:  1 00-0  João              Não
#> 2:  2 11-1 Marta              Sim
#> 3:  3 22-2 Jonas              Sim
```

---

## Dados

```
banco1 <- read.csv(text = "
  id,cpf,nome
  1,00-0,João
  2,11-1,Marta
  3,22-2,Jonas")

banco2 <- read.csv(text = "
  id,cpf,nome
  1,00-0,Robson
  2,11-1,Marta
  3,22-2,Jonas")
```

Answer (score 2):

Em R base pode-se usar o `merge` para ver quais linhas existem nos dois bancos de dados. Com o argumento `all.x = TRUE` se a linha não existir no outro banco, o valor é `NA`, que depois pode ser testado.

Na primeira maneira o resultado final é lógico `FALSE/TRUE`.

```r
banco1 <- merge(banco1, cbind(banco2, existe_em_banco2 = TRUE), all.x = TRUE)
banco1$existe_em_banco2 <- !is.na(banco1$existe_em_banco2)
banco1
#>   id cpf  nome existe_em_banco2
#> 1  1 000  João            FALSE
#> 2  2 111 Marta             TRUE
#> 3  3 222 Jonas             TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Se quiser a saída tal e qual está na pergunta, mais uma instrução resolve o problema.

```r
banco1 <- merge(banco1, cbind(banco2, existe_em_banco2 = TRUE), all.x = TRUE)
banco1$existe_em_banco2 <- !is.na(banco1$existe_em_banco2)
banco1$existe_em_banco2 <- c("Não", "Sim")[1L + banco1$existe_em_banco2]
banco1
#>   id cpf  nome existe_em_banco2
#> 1  1 000  João              Não
#> 2  2 111 Marta              Sim
#> 3  3 222 Jonas              Sim
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Dados

```r
banco1 <- read.table(text = "
id  cpf     nome    existe_em_banco2*
1   000     João    Não
2   111     Marta   Sim
3   222     Jonas   Sim", header = TRUE, colClasses = "character")
banco1  <- banco1[-4]

banco2 <- read.table(text = "
id  cpf     nome
1   000     Robson
2   111     Marta
3   222     Jonas", header = TRUE, colClasses = "character")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: MUITO obrigado! deu um baita norte.

Answer (score 2):

Aproveitando as tabelas construídas pelo @Rui Barradas, segue uma sugestão usando {tidyverse}:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Para uma saída com resultados lógicos:

```
banco1 %>% 
  left_join(banco2, by = c("id", "cpf")) %>% 
  mutate(existe_em_banco_2 = if_else(condition = nome.x == nome.y,
                                     true = TRUE,
                                     false = FALSE))


  id cpf nome.x nome.y existe_em_banco_2
1  1 000   João Robson             FALSE
2  2 111  Marta  Marta              TRUE
3  3 222  Jonas  Jonas              TRUE
```

Para uma saída com resultados "sim" ou "não":

```
banco1 %>% 
  left_join(banco2, by = c("id", "cpf")) %>% 
  mutate(existe_em_banco_2 = if_else(condition = nome.x == nome.y,
                                     true = "Sim",
                                     false = "Não"))

  id cpf nome.x nome.y existe_em_banco_2
1  1 000   João Robson               Não
2  2 111  Marta  Marta               Sim
3  3 222  Jonas  Jonas               Sim
```

Comment: vocês são mil! muito obrigado, gente! obrigado, mesmo.